# post request with multiple header information using fuel

Tags: kotlin, httprequest

I try to send a post request written in kotlin and b using the fuel framework (https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel). However, I need to send a json body with the post request as well as basic authentication credentials.

This is my current attempt which always leasds to an HTTP Exception 400. So I have the feeling there is something wrong with the way I send the body. I just cannot figure out what it is:

```
val myJsonBody = " {\n" +
        "        \"jql\": \"component = LOLO AND fixVersion = '18/3 Patch-2'\",\n" +
        "        \"startAt\": 0,\n" +
        "        \"maxResults\": 300,\n" +
        "        \"fields\": [\n" +
        "        \"issuetype\",\n" +
        "        \"created\",\n" +
        "        \"status\",\n" +
        "        \"summary\",\n" +
        "        \"customfield_10002\",\n" +
        "        \"customfield_10003\",\n" +
        "        \"customfield_11201\",\n" +
        "        \"customfield_10006\"\n" +
        "        ]\n" +
        "    }"
val confluenceUrl = "https://atc.mywebpage.net/jira/rest/api/2/search"

val (ignoredRequest, ignoredResponse, result) =
Fuel.post(confluenceUrl)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header(user,password)
        .jsonBody(myJsonBody)
        .responseString ()

result.fold({ print("success: $result") }, { print("failure: $result") })
```

The functioning cURL request generated by postman looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://atc.mywebpage.net/jira/rest/api/2/search \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "jql": "component = LOLO AND fixVersion = '\''18/3 Patch-2'\''",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 300,
    "fields": [
        "issuetype",
        "created",
        "status",
        "summary",
        "customfield_10002",
        "customfield_10003",
        "customfield_11201",
        "customfield_10006"
    ]
}'
```

Comment: You should use `.body(json.toString())` to send this as string I believe.

Comment: did you try executing the same request with other tools (e.g., cmd line, postman) to verify whether it is correct? Btw in this case probably a raw string (enclosed in `"""`) would be more readable

Comment: yes, I am using postman and the post request just works fine.

Comment: The .toString() solution is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I played around a little and I found out that I had to use authentication().basic() to access properly and not header(). This is the result:

```
    val confluenceUrl = "https://atc.mywebpage.net/jira/rest/api/2/search"
    val user = "myUser"
    val password = "myPassword"
    val myJsonBody = """
{
    "jql": "component = LOLO AND fixVersion = '18/3 Patch-2'",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 300,
    "fields": [
        "issuetype",
        "created",
        "status",
        "summary",
        "customfield_10002",
        "customfield_10003",
        "customfield_11201",
        "customfield_10006"
    ]
}
        """.trimIndent()

    val (ignoredRequest, ignoredResponse, result) =
    Fuel.post(confluenceUrl)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .authentication().basic(user, password)
            .jsonBody(myJsonBody)
            .responseString ()

    result.fold({ print("success: $result") }, { print("failure: $result") })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing that request manually. Use fiddler/postman/your preferred HTTP client. Maybe you're missing something in the body or headers?

Also I recommend a raw string literal. It's much more readable.

```
val myJsonBody = """
{
    "jql": "component = LOLO AND fixVersion = '18/3 Patch-2'",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 300,
    "fields": [
        "issuetype",
        "created",
        "status",
        "summary",
        "customfield_10002",
        "customfield_10003",
        "customfield_11201",
        "customfield_10006"
    ]
}
        """.trimIndent()

        val confluenceUrl = "https://atc.mywebpage.net/jira/rest/api/2/search"

        val (ignoredRequest, ignoredResponse, result) =
            Fuel.post(confluenceUrl)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header(user,password)
                .jsonBody(myJsonBody)
                .responseString ()

        result.fold({ print("success: $result") }, { print("failure: $result") })
```

Comment: In Postman, the post request works fine. All I have to add to the request is - of course - the request url, the body which is exactly the raw json string I added to my Kotlin project and basic authentication.